# What happens to a process when it's overlayed with a new process in Windows

Tags: windows, process, exec, child-process, spawn

In Windows, the `_spawn` functions, [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2), are able to overlay a parent process with a child process when you pass the `_P_OVERLAY` flag.

From the docs:

> Overlays a calling process with a new process, destroying the calling process

The question is, what happens to the parent proccess when it's destroyed, does it have a chance to clean things up or to terminate safely?

Or is it just wiped out from memory with no oportunity to do anything after the `_spawn` function call?

Comment: with `_P_OVERLAY` flag will be called [`_exit(0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/exit-exit-exit) at the end of api.

Comment: I suppose they named it `_P_OVERLAY` in case they ever supported a platform with `fork`, but in Windows this feature (and the `exec` family that uses it) is just a nuisance. Nothing gets 'overlayed', and for console applications it's a complete mess since a waiting parent process will resume console I/O in competition with the spawned process. It's better to spawn the child, wait for it to exit, and proxy its exit code. It's even better to add the spawned child to a Job that's configured to kill on close.